# Ionic Serve. Application not found

Tags: server, angular, ionic2, devops

I've been working on project in Ionic2 on the other computer.

When I do `ionic serve` on my PC it pops an error.

**192.168.1.100:8100 Application not found**

I set my app to have a static IP...

How do I solve this?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be the firewall blocking it. Have you tried turning it off?